# Can't enter double variable

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Interest rate,number of years,loan amount; display the monthly total payments



        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Ask for interest rate
        System.out.println("Enter your interest rate : ");


        //Get interest rate
        double interestRate = input.nextDouble();

        //Ask number of years
        System.out.println("Enter the number of years for this loan : ");


        //Get number of years
        double numberOfYears = input.nextDouble();

        //Ask for loan amount
        System.out.println("Enter your loan amount : ");
        //Get loan amount
        double loanAmount = input.nextDouble();


        //Monthly interest rate
        double monthlyInterestRate = interestRate / 12;

        //Monthly payment
        double monthlyPayment = (loanAmount * monthlyInterestRate) /
                1 - 1 / Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterestRate, numberOfYears*12)
                ;

        //Total payment
        System.out.println("total payment is : " + monthlyPayment * 12 * numberOfYears);
    }
```

When I enter a interest rate as my first input, for example `2.5` or `2.0` it gives

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
        at Sal.main(Sal.java:17)
```

I put in double variable, it wants integer. I don't understand. And yes I did import Scanner and type my class. I bought my computer 1 week ago. Same code should work fine because it was from my exercise book.

Comment: It may be locale specific. Try with comma instead of dot.

Comment: Thanks for edits. This is my first time asking anything. Sorry for mistakes

Comment: It is locale specific. Instead of `.` try with `,` or vice versa

Comment: @Pshemo thank you it works. How can I change it from locale to other?

Comment: Take a look at solution from duplicate question (link should be at top, you may need to refresh this page to see it).

Comment: Adding `scan.useLocale(Locale.US);`  might solve, use it before you read all the values!

Comment: Its amazing how quickly everybody answers. Thank you all. More research, less question is actual lesson for me.